# IIS URL 301 rewrite / redirect not working

Tags: url, redirect, iis, url-rewriting

I'm trying to do a 301 redirect using the IIS URL rewrite module.
I've googled, looked at videos and put in different settings but it does nothing...meaning, the link I set up the redirect on still just works as before. I don't even get an error.

Here are my settings:

- Requested URL: Matches the pattern
- Using: Regular expressions << I've tried 'exact match' as well...same result, didn't work.
- Pattern: Turf/ProductView.cfm?P=151
- Ignore Case: checked
- Action type: redirect
- Redirect URL: [https://www.weathermatic.com/products/6000-pro-rotors/{R:0}](https://www.weathermatic.com/products/6000-pro-rotors/%7BR:0%7D)
- Redirect Type: permanent 301

I've also tried using a Redirect URL that was within the same domain as the link I'm trying to redirect...again, nothing happens, the link still just works as before and no errors either.

Any help is so much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Query string is not included in Match URL and? have different meaning in regex expression.

Please use {REUEST_URI} and \? instead.

```
<rule name="rewrite rule" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/Turf/ProductView.cfm\?P=151" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.weathermatic.com/products/6000-pro-rotors/{R:0}" />
```

It will redirect Turf/ProductView.cfm?P=15 to https://www.weathermatic.com/products/6000-pro-rotors/Turf/ProductView.cfm?P=151

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you so much.

Comment: @DanRollans. Request you to accept the answer. So the reply can help more people.